# How to get a string variable from another class

Tags: java, variables, program-entry-point

There are 2 `main` in the 2-class:

- The class `New_String` is used to read text file from my file.
- The class `Write` is used to show the read value `S1(=ar[1])` from the `New_String` class.

However, no matter how I tried, the `Write` class is only showing `null`，or it throws a `NullPointerException` error.

Because the program has further function in my next stage, I can’t just combine the 2 class in one. Please tell me how to adjust.

**`write`**

```
public class write
{
    //public static String getar=get.ar[1];
    //getar = get.ar[];
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
     New_string file = new New_string();
     //site.readline
     System.out.println(file.S1);
     //String S1 = ar[1];

   }
}
```

**`New_string`**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class New_string
{
    public static String S1;
    public static int a=0;
    public static String ar[];
    public static int lnum=0;
    public static String line=null;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
     FileReader fr= new FileReader("read_listflow.txt");
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

     while ((line=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
         lnum=lnum+1;
     }

     FileReader fr1= new FileReader("read_listflow.txt");
     BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);
     ar=new String[lnum];

     while ((line=br1.readLine())!=null)
     {
         ar[a]=line;
         a=a+1;
     }

     S1 = ar[1];
     }
}
```

Comment: each main() runs in its own instance of JVM as individual processes.. So, basically you have 2 processes running now.. Not 2 threads of the same process.. So, 2 processes can't share data without IPC.

Comment: Well, you're probabilly launching your application using as main function the one in the write class. So the main function in the New_string class is never called, hence the New_string.S1 field is null. The fact that you have two main methods in two different classes does not mean that EACH of the is called when you launch your program unsing ONE of them. Your main method inside write should first call New_string.main(null), before expecting to have a chance at a non-null value inside New_string.S1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main method will not automatically be called when you instantiate a class. You need to explicitly call the method of class to get the work done.

You have to do something like this..

```
public class NewString
{
    public static String S1;
    public static int a=0;
    public static String ar[];
    public static int lnum=0;
    public static String line=null;

    public String read() throws IOException
    {
    FileReader fr= new FileReader("read_listflow.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        lnum=lnum+1;
    }

    FileReader fr1= new FileReader("read_listflow.txt");
    BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);
    ar=new String[lnum];
    while ((line=br1.readLine())!=null)
    {
        ar[a]=line;
        a=a+1;
    }
    S1 = ar[1];
    return S1;
    }

}
```

and then

```
public class Write
{

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
     New_string file = new New_string();

     System.out.println(file.read());
   }
}
```

Also, please follow ***Java Naming conventions***

Comment: we have even used exactly same names for the method! :) :p

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to add a method read in your New_string class and call that method in your write class 
 I have done the changes

```
public class write
    {
        //public static String getar=get.ar[1];
        //getar = get.ar[];
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
       {
        New_string file = new New_string();
          file.read()
         //site.readline
         System.out.println(file.S1);
         //String S1 = ar[1];

       }
    }
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class New_string
{
    public static String S1;
    public static int a=0;
    public static String ar[];
    public static int lnum=0;
    public static String line=null;
public read(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
     FileReader fr= new FileReader("read_listflow.txt");
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
     while ((line=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
     lnum=lnum+1;
     }

     FileReader fr1= new FileReader("read_listflow.txt");
     BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);
     ar=new String[lnum];
     while ((line=br1.readLine())!=null)
     {
     ar[a]=line;
     a=a+1;
     }
     S1 = ar[1];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad code, but the following just does your dirty job :)

```
public class write
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  {
        New_string.main(mull);
        System.out.println(New_string.S1);
    }
}
```